# Topic modeling with Spacy - not making very good predictions

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am working on a topic modelling task, whereby I am taking peoples feedback (text) and trying to extract the important topics from them.

The feedback is quite short, and I don't know if that is what is posing us the problem. Below is my code, is there anything really obvious I have missed?

I am removing stop words, lemmatizing, keeping only nouns and removing stop words. However I pass these into the model, it's not working quite as I hoped

One of the big issues is semantics, the customer can refer to the same concept in different ways : shop, boutique, store, supermarket, etc... They are all referring to the shop, but the LDA sees these as different concepts and dumps them into different topics, even though 'I love the store' and 'I love the shop' are the same statement.

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

#set display options
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 0)

#ingest data
df = pd.read_csv('surv.csv')

#import spacy language library and stopword dictionary
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
all_stopwords = nlp.Defaults.stop_words

#Limit DF to columns of interest and drop nulls
responses = df[['Comment', 'score']]
responses = responses.dropna()

#lemmatize the strings
def cleanup(row):
    comment = row['Comment']
    comment = nlp(comment)
    sent = []
    for word in comment:
        sent.append(word.lemma_)    
    return " ".join(sent)

#keep only nouns
def only_nouns(row):
    comment = row['nostops']
    blob = TextBlob(comment)
    x = blob.noun_phrases
    return " ".join(x)

def pos(row):
    comment = row['nostops']
    comment = nlp(comment)
    nouns = []
    i=0
    while i < len(comment)-1:
        if comment[i].pos_ == 'NOUN':
            nouns.append(comment[i])
        i=i+1
    return nouns
        
#remove the stop words
def remove_stops(row):
    comment = row['Comment']
    comment = comment.split(' ')  
    rem = []
    for word in comment:
        if word not in all_stopwords:
            rem.append(word)
    return " ".join(rem)

#What entities are defined in the document
def split_entities(row):
    comment = row['Comment']
    comment = nlp(comment)
    entities = []
    for ent in comment.ents:
        entities.append(ent)
    return entities          

#Call functions
responses['lemmas'] = responses.apply(cleanup,axis=1)            
responses['nostops'] = responses.apply(remove_stops,axis=1)
responses['nouns'] = responses.apply(pos, axis=1)
responses['nouns2'] = responses.apply(only_nouns, axis=1)
responses['entities'] = responses.apply(split_entities,axis=1)


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
cv = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.9, min_df=2, stop_words='english') 
document_term_matrix = cv.fit_transform(responses['nouns'])
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=4, random_state=42)
lda.fit(document_term_matrix)
topic_results = lda.transform(document_term_matrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

**General suggestion**: Did you try and add [TF-IDF in sklearn?](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html) It's good general way to weigh words based on how often they occur in documents and across documents and it improves the quality of LDA output. You can add it together with the 'CountVectorizer'. Here is a good full example from the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html#topic-extraction-with-non-negative-matrix-factorization-and-latent-dirichlet-allocation).

**Specific suggestion** for the issue of words you would like to treat as synonyms ("shop, boutique, store, supermarket"): I think I would add a pre-processing step where I replace all of these separate words with the exact same token (e.g. convert all occurrences of "shop, boutique, store, supermarket" to "store"). It requires the manual creation of synonym lists, but it's an easy way of solving the issue.